# Javascript object function is returning null

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, require

I'm trying to do a very simple OOP in Javascript (Node.js) but having issues. I tried everything already, including searching, but did not find an answer.

Basically, I have this file Test.js:

```
class Test {

constructor(){
    this.name = 'Hey';
    this.config = 'null!';
    console.log('this.config: ' + this.config);
}

config(msg){
    this.config = msg;
    console.log('new this.config: ' + this.config);
}

}

module.exports = Test;
```

(I also tried this:)

```
function Test()
{
    this.name = 'Hey';
    this.config = 'null!';
    console.log('this.config: ' + this.config);
}

Test.config = function(msg) // and Test.prototype.config
{
    this.config = msg;
    console.log('new this.config: ' + this.config);
}

module.exports = Test;
```

And I have this other file app.js:

```
var TestModule = require('./Test.js');
var Test = new TestModule();
var test = Test.config('hi');
```

Other way I've tried:

```
var TestModule = require('./Test.js');
var Test = new TestModule().config('hi');
```

and also did not work.

I tried many different things already, but no matter what, when I try to run the config function in the same instance, the object turns null... does anyone know why that happens? Maybe I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: your `config()` function has no `return` statement.

Comment: And if you're not using `class` notation it should definitely be `Test.prototype.config`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first snippet is correct

```
class Test {

    constructor() {
      this.name = 'Hey';
      this.config = 'null!';
      console.log('this.config: ' + this.config);
    }

    config(msg) {
      this.config = msg;
      console.log('new this.config: ' + this.config);
    }

  }

  module.exports = Test;
```

`config` is an instance method not a class method or static method.

You need to call `config()` on a Test instance. like

```
var Test = require('./Test.js');
var testObj = new Test();
```

Now `testObj` is instance and you can call `config()` method on this object.

```
test.config('Hi');
```

It will print/log a message but it will not return any thing but `undefined` because you are not returning anything from that method.

I hope this explains the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, it would be possible to do it by `new Test().config('hi')` if I actually used the "constructor" on the config function, right?

Comment: yeah you are right but you can't assign this to some variable because it returns nothing.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your `var Test` to be the `return` value of the `config` function.

```
var test = Test.config('hi!');
```

As `config` does not return anything, this will result in `test` being null.

You should either make your `config` method return something (this would be a form of the ["method chaining" design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)), or simply not assign the result of the `config` call to a variable.

For example, you could simply do this:

```
var test = new TestModule();
test.config('hi!');
// the 'test' variable still contains a reference to your test module
```